# standard and efficient map between objects

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am working on clustering problem where I have something called *distance matrix*. This distance matrix is something like:
[image: Distance Matrix]

1. the number of nodes(g) are N (dynamic)
2. This matrix is Symmetric (dist[i,j]==dist[j,i])
3. g1,g2,.... are object (they contain strings , integers and may even more..)
4. I want to be able to reach any value by simple way like dist[4][3] or even more clear way like dist(g1,g5) (here g1 and g5 may be some kind of pointer or reference)
5. many std algorithm will be applied on this distance matrix like min, max, accumulate ..etc
6. preferably but not mandatory, I would like not to use boost or other 3rd party libraries

What is the best standard way to declare this matrix.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I would use three vectors. One to store the row names, one to store the column names, and one to store the distance values.

Comment: @barry I thought that it may be a famous problem as many people who work in the Machine Learning field may face it before. However, I will see if I can provide more details.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two dimensional vector like so

```
std::vector<std::vector<float> > table(N, std::vector<float>(N));
```

don`t forget to initialize it like this, it reserves memory for N members, so it does not need to reallocate all the members then you are adding more. And does not fragment the memory.
you can access its members like so

```
table[1][2] = 2.01;
```

it does not uses copy constructors all the time because vector index operator returns a reference to a member;
so it is pretty efficient if N does not need to change.